# Eclipse bin folder location

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is a simple question where can I find the bin folder where all my android apps are executed on eclipse?

I want to be able to get a specific apk produced during debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be located in Projectname > bin > res

It should be generated the once there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

In Project Explorer (not Package Explorer). Here you click the triangle and select Customize View and remove the click on Java output folders